# Why isn't Auxillary Inclined Plane called Auxillary horizontal plane?

Tags: drawing

Sectional plane inclined to VP is called as Auxillary Vertical plane, then why is a sectional plane inclined to HP called as Auxillary Inclined Plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auxiliary inclined plane (blue) is not horizontal, think it as a tilted horizontal(=green) plane. Auxiliary VP is still vertical. It's parallel with Z axis. AIP is parallel with X or Y axis.

[image]